# PayPal Donate Button Redirect After Payment

Tags: php, paypal, redirect, paypal-ipn

I know how to make a PayPal donate button redirect after payment, but what I need to know is, can you pass the payed amount through this redirection. So it would redirect to `http://example.com/donate?amount=123`, is this even possible?
Thanks!

EDIT: It seems I can do it with IPN(?), I just don't know how to use paypal's IPN, can anyone help me? (yes I have read the docs, they are confusing)

Comment: wouldn't an attacker likely redirect to http://example.com/donate?amount=999999999999999 after only having donated 1? better call the paypal api using some kind of transaction_id that is provided with the return-url and ask paypal directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is possible, like so:

```
<!-- where you setup your paypal button : -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/donate?amount=<?php echo $amount ?>" />
```

**But (concerning security)**

It would be better to keep it in e.g. `$_SESSION['amount']` along with a reference id `$_SESSION['reference_id'] = md5('whatever you like' . 'plus salt');`

And in the paypal button use that reference_id like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/donate?ref=<?php echo $_SESSION['reference_id'] ?>" />
```

And then, `if $_GET['ref'] == $_SESSION['reference_id']`, then you can use the $_SESSION['amount'] variable.

Comment: The problem is though, It is a donate button, so the user inputs how much they are donating AFTER clicking the button :/

Comment: I think that you can configure that: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_donation_buttons#id08AAF0M0NNW.

Comment: I think that the difference between the buy now and the donate button is only the image