# Paypal donate: Send and receive data

Tags: php, paypal

I have created a PayPal [donation form with fields](http://www.schechter.ac.il/donations/) and I would like to save info about my donors.
Once a person fills in the details and press the donate button he/she will be redirected to Paypal to complete payment details, once that's done they will be redirected to a thank you page on my domain and shown the transaction details and their own.

The problem is that I can't seem to pass paypal the form details, is that even possible? which fields paypal is willing to accept (their docs seems outdated everywhere I check)? what's the best way to solve this problem?

The code is already written, all the re-directions and form is setup well, the problem is that I can't seem to pass the values to paypal.
e.g. I have the input field `amount` and when you press the donate button you're redirected to Paypal and have to insert the amount again. Another example is choosing a currency, there is an input field to determine which currency the person wants to pay with, when you arrive at paypal's website it's fixed to USD.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: good ?, thinking about this too,

Answer (score 0):

before when I tried doing paypal, I just need 1 custom value to pass on before processing, we usually put it as a hidden field element example

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="mycustomvalue">
```

here this might give you an idea [link1](http://www.brianmoreau.com/articles/paypal_buy_now_button_sending_custom_variables.php)  or [link2](http://www.michaelsherron.com/paypal-IPN-custom-variables)

For the currency I made something before accepting USD, but when some of our user made payments using paypal with SGD or other currency, paypal automatically converts the amount to USD (with the daily rate). With regards to the passing of currency type from your form, haven't tried but this [multiple currency link](https://www.paypal.com/ph/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_wa-outside) might help.

Comment: That's what I'm saying! I have `<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">` exactly like that but when you go to the paypal page you see it's in USD. This input type works only if you setup a buy now button, not a donations button.

Comment: One more thing, the custom field is only limited to 256 characters as far as I know.

Comment: +1 for the question anyway, this might add to our knowledge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548856/paypal-custom-amount-for-donate-now-button?rq=1                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134865/paypal-donation-button-adding-amount-and-currency?rq=1                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382985/paypal-donate-button-redirect-after-payment?rq=1